# Nested Json response in Swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I am trying to write an example response in Swagger UI that would depict the below JSON structure.

```
Ids_Match": [ {"id": "1", "value": .89},  {"id": "2", "value": .82}]
Ids_MisMatch": [ {"id": "3", "value": .56},  {"id": "4", "value": .61}]
```

Below is my structure but i am not able to make the response look like above

```
responses:
    200:
      description: successful operation
      examples:
        application/json: { "Ids_Match":{{"id":1,"value":0.89},{"id": "2", "value": .82}}}
        }
    400:
      description: Invalid status value
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: API description in Markdown.
  version: 1.0.0
host: api.example.com
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  - https

paths:
  /find:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: successful operation
          examples:
            application/json:
              Ids_Match: [ {"id": "1", "value": .89},  {"id": "2", "value": .82}]
              Ids_MisMatch: [ {"id": "3", "value": .56},  {"id": "4", "value": .61}]
```

It renders as following:

[image: sample]